# Gin framework can not get the data from Postman

Tags: go, go-gin

Gin framework can not get the data from Postman,below is a demo:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)



type CreateRequest struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Phone    string `json:"phone"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}


func Signup(c *gin.Context) {
    var r CreateRequest
    if err := c.Bind(&r); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("this is debug info:start")
    fmt.Println(r.Username)
    fmt.Println("this is debug info:end")
}



func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.POST("/signup", Signup)
    
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

Send a request from postman:

[image: Postman screenshot]

Debug info:

[image: debugger screenshot]

Where is the problem?
What should I do?

Comment: picture cracks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accordingly to your screen it looks like you're sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` request and it this case you have to have `form` tags in your `CreateRequest` struct:

```
type CreateRequest struct {
    Username string `json:"username" form:"username"`
    Phone    string `json:"phone" form:"phone"`
    Password string `json:"password" form:"password"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `form:"username"` in order to POST using URI. Unless you want to POST it using body JSON, then you can only set `json:"username"` in your struct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31238378)